# Java Sorting list alpha

Tags: java

I'm trying to sort the list alphabetically 
Unit class has: name  and number. I'm trying to sort by name.

using my code it's sorted but not alphabetically.
My code is: (tried both the commented and the not commented one.

```
List<Unit> yards = new ArrayList<>(unitsApi.getAllUnits());

Collections.sort(yards, new BeanComparator<Unit>("name"));

//another try
    List<Unit> sortedNames = yards.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());

//num3 another
            //List<Unit> sortedList = yards
                 .stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Object::toString))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    model.addAttribute("yards", sortedList);
```

Comment: `yards.sort(Comparator.comparingBy(Unit::name))`

Comment: that's not correrct ... The method comparingBy(Unit::name) is undefined for the type Comparator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the sort key i.e:

```
List<Unit> sortedList = yards.stream()
                             .sorted(Comparator.comparing(e -> e.getName()))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```